# Problems with SSL (Apache and Django)

Tags: apache, ssl

I can't seem to get SSL to work.  I spent maybe 15 hours trying to get my website to work with HTTPS.
I got my SSL certificate from Comodo.  I followed [these directions](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203&nav=0,96,1,95).

I first tried to edit the correct fields in my ssl.conf, but i ended up just adding another virtual host in my httpd.conf.  However either way didn't allow me to access my site with https.

My website is [foodchute.com](http://www.foodchute.com/).  I have no idea what to do and I've been messing around with apache and ssl for the past few days.  Any help would be awesome.

Side note: does my certificate chain file need to be PEM encoded?  My chain file only consists of 4 certificates.  I looked at some default chain file and I saw a bunch of certificates plus other information like this:

```
Certificate:

Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        61:8d:c7:86:3b:01:82:05
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: CN=ACEDICOM Root, OU=PKI, O=EDICOM, C=ES
    Validity
        Not Before: Apr 18 16:24:22 2008 GMT
        Not After : Apr 13 16:24:22 2028 GMT
    Subject: CN=ACEDICOM Root, OU=PKI, O=EDICOM, C=ES
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (4096 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:ff:92:95:e1:68:06:76:b4:2c:c8:58:48:ca:fd:
                80:54:29:55:63:24:ff:90:65:9b:10:75:7b:c3:6a:
                db:62:02:01:f2:18:86:b5:7c:5a:38:b1:e4:58:b9:
                fb:d3:d8:2d:9f:bd:32:37:bf:2c:15:6d:be:b5:f4:
                21:d2:13:91:d9:07:ad:01:05:d6:f3:bd:77:ce:5f:
                42:81:0a:f9:6a:e3:83:00:a8:2b:2e:55:13:63:81:
                ca:47:1c:7b:5c:16:57:7
```

these are my files.
httpd.conf

```
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute
    ServerName www.foodchute.com
    #Redirect / https://23.23.93.154/
    ErrorLog /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/logs/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/logs/apache_access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/foodchute/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/foodchute>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/images>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/foodchute>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #LogLevel warn

    #Alias /media/ /home/djangotest/helloworld/media

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/foodchute.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/foodchute.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/foodchute.ca-bundle

    DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute
    ServerName www.foodchute.com
    #Redirect / https://23.23.93.154/
    ErrorLog /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/logs/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/logs/apache_access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/foodchute/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/foodchute>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/images>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/foodchute>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #LogLevel warn

    #Alias /media/ /home/djangotest/helloworld/media

</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath /home/ec2-user/foodchute/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages

Alias /static/ /home/ec2-user/foodchute/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/
```

wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for foodchute project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.

"""
import os,sys

apache_configuration = os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute')
sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/foodchute')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "foodchute.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this.  I forgot to open up port 423 for my amazon ec2 instance......Problem solved.